# EclipseLink 2.3.3 fails to update versioned entity on PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple entity (some irrelevant fields ommited for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant")
public class Tenant {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Version @Column
    private long version = 0;

    @Column(name = "init_in_progress")
    private Boolean initializationInProgress;

}
```

I want to do a bulk update on all tenants by setting `true` to `initializationInProgress` using a JPA update query like this:

```
    entityManager.createQuery(
            "UPDATE Tenant t " +
            "SET t.initializationInProgress = :ip")
        .setParameter("ip", initializationInProgress)
        .executeUpdate();
```

And this works fine with `EclipseLink 2.2.1`. But when I try the same with version `2.3.3`, then I get an error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.3.v20120629-r11760): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE tenant SET version = (SELECT (version + ?) FROM tenant WHERE ID = tenant.ID), init_in_progress = ?
    bind => [1, true]
Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=Tenant sql="UPDATE tenant SET version = (SELECT (version + ?) FROM tenant WHERE ID = tenant.ID), init_in_progress = ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1494)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateAll(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateAllQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(UpdateAllQuery.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ModifyAllQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ModifyAllQuery.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeUpdate(EJBQueryImpl.java:540)
    at com.example.dao.impl.tenant.TenantRepositoryImpl.updateAllTenantsInitializationStatus(TenantRepositoryImpl.java:100)
```

Is anyone familiar with this bug? Any known workarounds/fixes (apart from not changing `EclipseLink` version)? Thanks for all your help.

BTW, I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This initially looked like a data issue, where you have multiple rows with the same ID in `tenant` ... but it's actually an issue with the EclipseLink query. Since that's a generated query, you appear to have a (serious) EclipseLink bug on your hands.

Update: See [this EclipseLink bugzilla entry for bug 393223](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393223).

The query should really alias the inner reference to `tenant`, eg:

```
UPDATE tenant SET version = (SELECT (t2.version + ?) FROM tenant t2 WHERE t2.ID = tenant.ID), init_in_progress = ?
```

Failure to add this alias means that `ID = tenant.ID` means `tenant.ID = tenant.ID` ... which is always true, so the subquery matches every row of `tenant`.

Observe this demo:

```
CREATE TABLE tenant ( ID integer primary key, version integer );
INSERT INTO tenant ( id, version ) values (1,0), (2,0), (3,0);

BEGIN;

PREPARE testq(integer) AS 
UPDATE tenant SET version = (SELECT (version + $1) FROM tenant WHERE ID = tenant.ID);

regress=> EXECUTE testq(1);
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

ROLLBACK;
```

Corrected query:

```
BEGIN;

PREPARE testq2(integer) AS 
UPDATE tenant SET version = (SELECT (version + $1) FROM tenant t2 WHERE t2.ID = tenant.ID);

regress=> EXECUTE testq2(1);
UPDATE 3

ROLLBACK;
```

This appears to be an EclipseLink bug. I don't see that there's much you can do about it in your code other than do the bulk update as native SQL.

Comment: it looked like a but to me too, but I couldn't find the bug report, so I thought that maybe I'm doing sth wrong, since the bug seems really a major one. Thank for your effort on the topic.